# How to query again based on ransack result in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

After getting ransack result like this in a controller:

```rb
@q = SomeModel.ransack(q)
```

I would like to query one more time based on the ransack result(`@q`).

```sql
SELECT * FROM ransack_result WHERE some_field IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Is there any way to apply additional query?

---

For more background information:

The `some_field` is encrypted with `ActiverRecord::Encryption` in Rails7. When I try to include the `WHERE some_field IN ('a', 'b', 'c')` by using `q[:some_field_in] = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, each of `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` is encrypted.

I'm in a transition period which `some_field` includes both encrypted and unencrypted value, so I want to query both encrypted & unencrypted data while keeping the other conditions.
ransack does not support encrypted attribute right now, so this is why I cannot use `*_in` matcher provided in ransack. :'(

OR... it would be nice if I could get the sql query generated by ransack in rails controller- then I will be able to append the above query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform an additional query based on the result obtained from Ransack, you can extract the SQL generated by Ransack and then "manually" add your custom query conditions:

```
@q = SomeModel.ransack(q)

# obtain generated SQL by Ransack
original_query = @q.result.arel.to_sql

# your manual modifications
custom_condition = "some_field IN ('a', 'b', 'c')"
custom_query = "#{original_query} AND #{custom_condition}"

# perform the SQL query
SomeModel.find_by_sql(custom_query)
```